ElasticSearch Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch C# Combine Actions on Index not working
I'm running the Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch and I want to delete all indexes associated with an alias and add a new one.  The following code works great hitting the API directly:
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": "_all",
        "alias": "search_question_elastic_search_model"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "search_question_elastic_search_model_20230628",
        "alias": "search_question_elastic_search_model"
      }
    }
  ]

In C# using the ElasticClient, I've replicated using the following:
        var response = await elasticClient.Indices.UpdateAliasesAsync(a => a
            .Actions(b => b
                .Remove(o => o
                    .Index(Indices.All.ToString())
                    .Alias(aliasName))
                .Add(n => n
                    .Index(currentIndex)
                    .Alias(aliasName))
            ));

There are no errors coming back; however, the Remove never is executed.  After running the above, my alias is pointing to 2 indexes.  When I look at the Debug information, I get the following:
Valid Elasticsearch response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /_aliases?pretty=true&error_trace=true

# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://elasticsearch.dev.local:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0838190
# Request:
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "alias": "search_question_elastic_search_model",
        "index": "search_question_elastic_search_model_20270928"
      }
    }
  ]
}
# Response:
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "errors" : false
}

# TCP states:
  Established: 90
  FinWait2: 1
  TimeWait: 156
  CloseWait: 13

# ThreadPool statistics:
  Worker: 
    Busy: 1
    Free: 32766
    Min: 22
    Max: 32767
  IOCP: 
    Busy: 0
    Free: 1000
    Min: 1
    Max: 1000

Am I doing something incorrectly or is this an issue with the ElasticClient?
